# Is there an R package for Monte Carlo simulations?

Tags: r, montecarlo

From a little searching, I have found [this](https://github.com/FunWithR/MonteCarlo) package, but a colleague tells me that it doesn't work in the latest version of R. This is the first time I'm using R and I get the feeling that trying to begin with something that might not work would be a bad place to start.

So, should I try with that package, is there an alternative, or should I just try to code the Monte Carlo simulations from scratch? (most of the Monte Carlo questions I can see look like they are done without a bespoke package)

Comment: I'm using the latest version of R and that package installed fine for me.

Comment: I think you may find that writing the simulations yourself using whatever RNG is available to you will be more performant and less prone to breaking.

Comment: See if these help https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/04/how-to-perform-monte-carlo-simulation/ https://bookdown.org/s3dabeck1984/bookdown-demo-master/monte-carlo-simulations.html

Comment: okay, these all answer my question nicely. Thanks!

Comment: There is a simstudy R package: https://rdrr.io/cran/simstudy/  I installed it but have not actually used it.  Variable correlation appears to be an important functionality included in the package which may simplify your model structure.